# How do I import a third party module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-2.x

I've found a third party module which I would like to use. How do I technically import that module?

Particularly, I want to use a module called [context_manager](https://github.com/cool-RR/GarlicSim-for-Python-3.x/blob/master/garlicsim_py3/garlicsim/general_misc/context_manager.py). obviously, I cannot just `import garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager`because it won't find `garlicsim`. So what should I write to import the thing?

**EDIT:** I'm using both Python 3.x and Python 2.x and I'd like to get answers relevant to both versions.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? That link is for a python 3 package.

Comment: @chmullig: I'm using both Python 2 and Python 3. Just added that to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In garlicsim's case you'd want to install it following garlicsim's [installation instructions](http://docs.garlicsim.org/intro/installation/python-3.x.html). You could also download the code and in the right directory run `python setup.py install` for this and almost any other library.

One note, since you may be new to python, is that that's a python 3 library. If you're using python 2 (more likely if you don't know) it won't work right. You'll want to install the python 2 [version](https://github.com/cool-RR/GarlicSim).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the module somewhere in your PYTHONPATH.  For nearly all python modules, you can use `easy_install` or the package's own `setup.py` script to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Installation

[GarlicSim is dead](http://blog.ram.rachum.com/post/24682447796/garlicsim-is-dead-long-live-python-toolbox) but [still](https://github.com/cool-RR/GarlicSim) [available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/garlicsim):

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip search garlicsim
garlicsim_lib             - Collection of GarlicSim simulation packages
garlicsim_lib_py3         - Collection of GarlicSim simulation packages
garlicsim_wx              - GUI for garlicsim, a Pythonic framework for
                            computer simulations
garlicsim                 - Pythonic framework for working with simulations
garlicsim_py3             - Pythonic framework for working with simulations
```

Use `pip install garlicsim` to install it.

## Usage

According to [the Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>   comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.
>
> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

```
>>> import garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager as CM
>>> help(CM)
Help on module garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager in garlicsim.general_misc:

NAME
    garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager - Defines the `ContextManager` and `ContextManagerType` classes.

FILE
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\garlicsim\general_misc\context_manager.py

DESCRIPTION
    Using these classes to define context managers allows using such context
    managers as decorators (in addition to their normal use) and supports writing
    context managers in a new form called `manage_context`. (As well as the
    original forms).
[...]
>>> from garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager import ContextManager
>>> help(ContextManager)
Help on class ContextManager in module garlicsim.general_misc.context_manager:

class ContextManager(__builtin__.object)
 |  Allows running preparation code before a given suite and cleanup after.
```

## Alternative

It looks like that's [already in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator):

> class contextlib.ContextDecorator - A base class that enables a context
>   manager to also be used as a decorator.

And [contextmanager is as old as Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tag(name):
    print "<%s>" % name
    yield
    print "</%s>" % name

>>> with tag("h1"):
...    print "foo"
...
<h1>
foo
</h1>
```